# 1-forms and zero simple

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

Let $\varphi$ a differential transformation such that $\varphi (x,y)=(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ and $D\subset U$ such that $\varphi$ restricted to $\partial D=\gamma$ be distinct zero and we define $i(\varphi ,D)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{\gamma }\theta _{0}$, where
$\theta _{0}=\frac{fdg-gdf}{f^{2}+g^{2}}$ a 1-form with $f^{2}+g^{2}\neq 0$.
We say $\varphi$ have a simple positive zero if $\varphi(p)=0$ and $det(D_{p}\varphi)>0$, conversely we say $\varphi$ have a simple negative zero if $\varphi(p)=0$ and $det(D_{p}\varphi)<0$.

If $\varphi$ have a simple zero then prove that $i(\varphi ,D)=\pm 1$

I have a hint; think in the expansion $\varphi (p)=D_{p}\varphi p+O(\left \| p \right \|^{2})$ and in the correct homotopy. I´ve tried to use the expresion, but I really don´t see how to use it. Of course I´ve already tried to attack the problem with out the hint, but I don´t see how is useful to know that $\int _{\gamma }f^{2}+g^{2}\neq 0$

I´ve been thinking in this problem for a few days, does anybody can help me? Beacause I´m really stuck with this.
Thanks!

Comment: What's $\gamma$?

Comment: @John sorry, I forgot that part, I´ve just correct it, $\gamma$ is the restriction of the border of $D$

Comment: I think I have the answer, I have to define a homotopy between $\phi$ and the linear part of $\phi$, right? I just have to find the homotopy